# Appcache Obsolete after Refresh Offline

Tags: html, html5-appcache, cache-manifest, offline-web-app

So I understand how a manifest file works and I am getting all the resource I need from the network tab in Chrome's developer console. When I turn off my server and run the webpage offline it works. But after the first refresh the page has the error HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found. I check what file was missing and it was the text/html that was the webpage and when I check the header

```
Request URL:https://offline1.exactbid.net/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:offline1.exactbid.net
Referer:https://offline1.exactbid.net/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/28.0.1500.63 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Connection:close
Content-Length:315
Content-Type:text/html; charset=us-ascii
Date:Fri, 28 Jun 2013 23:09:27 GMT
Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2
```

**UPDATE**

So it seems that after I refresh the page everything I had in the appcache disappeared. Does it have to do with the Cache-Control:max-age=0, I read some stuff online and it says that it is similar to no-cache. is that correct?

It seems that when I try to start the page offline it says that the cache is obsolete

Comment: What does it say in Chrome's F12 resources area? It should list all of the resources cached offline.

Comment: @Dai It list all the files that I have in the manifest file. But after I refresh the page it all disappear :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after experimenting I figure the what but not the why. I was using ASP. net for the web page and I did not have a site master page so I was declaring it in my default.aspx directly. But after I changed my code to have a site master page and declares the manifest file there it fixed the problem. When I am offline and refresh the manifest download fails (suppose to happen) and does not label the appcache as obsolete. I hope this helps someone. **If someone knows the why I would mark that as the answer until then this is it**